# Asymptotic translation length on the complex of curves and the forgetful map

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $\phi$ be a pseudo-Anosov on a surface with punctures with asymptotic translation length $L(\phi)$.  If under the forgetful map $\phi$ restricts to a pseudo-Anosov $\hat{\phi}$ on a connected subsurface with asymptotic translation length $L(\hat{\phi})$ is $L(\phi)\geq L(\hat{\phi})$?

This would be the analogy for dilatations of these mapping classes.

Comment: A mapping class fixing a subsurface (up to isotopy) preserves the boundary curves, and is therefore reducible and not pseudo-Anosov.